# Post C# MultipartFormContent application/octet-stream Winform HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to post one or more files from my local machine to an API with `HttpClient`, `MultipartFormContent` and ContentType: `"application/octet-stream"` but when i do postSync and call an API from a local Winform application,  the result of the task (`var response = task.Result;`) says that it is "Unsopported Type File" StatusCode: 415. I tried with `ByteArrayContent` but was still unsuccessful.

This is my code:

```
    bool Upload(string url, string path, string localFilename, string fileName, string projectId, string folderId)
    {
        Boolean isFileUploaded = false;
        string xapiKey = "-----";
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", xapiKey);

            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(localFilename);
            FileUpload uploadResult = null;
            bool _fileUploaded = false;

            //Extract content file
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
            streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "\"" + Path.GetFileName(path) + "\"";
            streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octetstream");
            string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);
            content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "mulitpart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            content.Add(streamContent);

            //content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), "\"file\"", string.Format("\"{0}\"", fileName + fileInfo.Extension));                

            Task taskUpload = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    var response = task.Result;
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        uploadResult = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<FileUpload>().Result;
                        if (uploadResult != null)
                            _fileUploaded = true;
                    }
                }

                fileStream.Dispose();
            });
            taskUpload.Wait();
            if (_fileUploaded)
                isFileUploaded = true;
            httpClient.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isFileUploaded = false;
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        return isFileUploaded;
    }
```

Comment: What API endpoint are you posting to? Do you have access to documentation or logs?

Comment: Not sure if you've tried it, but you may need to use `multipart/form-data` instead of  `application/octetstream` for content type if the API is expecting form-type content.

Comment: The API method is as follows: public async Task <ApiResult> PostFilePGAsync (string idProject, string idFolder, string fileName, IFormFile fileRequestPost) those parameters are what you expect.

Comment: Set the ContentType to `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/octetstream`. ----Change the line of code to `streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")`

Comment: thanks everyone,

i resolved the problem adding the follow code line:

 streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "\"NameFolder"\"";

NameFolder is the place where saved the files 

sorry for my english....